# Join many tables sql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to create a view of my database. \in fact, my database contains around 20 tables and i want to join the tables based on the foreign keys but there are some duplicates columns. Is there an easy and fast way to do it ?

Comment: What does "some duplicates columns" mean?  Why is that making your joins difficult?

Comment: i have same columns name in many tables and the join sql is outputting duplicate columns and if I want to change the variable name of the columns it will take me lifetime :?

Comment: Is this mysql, sqlserver, oracle, etc?

Comment: Well, I mean there are text editors and query analyzers that can make it easier to do that.  If you're joining 20 tables and actually need all data from all tables for your query, there really isn't an easy way to do that directly, no.  It's exceptionally rare to need that much data in one query.

Comment: but what if i want to create a view for my database ? @BaconBits

Comment: Then create a view of what is needed for that situation. I find it very hard to believe that you have a common use case for a view that selects every field from every table in the DB unless the amount of data is very small. Keep in mind that it's not going to be fast to do this unless the number of rows in your DB is small. The larger the query, the more memory and CPU required. If you use a single view for everything, that means the simplest of queries is as difficult as the most complex possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that might help. You'll have to list out the columns if you do not want the dupes. You can run

**[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7913a/15)**

```
select group_concat(concat(table_name,'.', column_name) separator ', ') 
from information_schema.columns
where table_name in ('Students', 'ClassRoster');
```

This will list [table_name].[column_name] for all the columns in the tables you specify in one long string. You can then copy the result and paste it next to the `SELECT` in your query and remove all the dupe columns if you know them. This query will show columns where there is more than one and show the table as well.

```
select table_name, column_name 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where column_name in (
  select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  group by COLUMN_NAME 
  having count(1) > 1)
order by column_name
```

It still is manual but will save you some time. With a little more effort you could tweak the queries to where the whole process is just one query and not manually remove anything.

Comment: @JadDaoud I added demo. Both queries are safe to run as they are only `select` on your database.

Comment: i like it but after i create the select concat query how can i access the attributes ? should i do another query ? suppose i want to create a view of the database .. please advise

Comment: The purpose of the first query is to list all the table.column names separated by comma. Then you would write your select but instead of manually typing out the 200 columns just copy and paste the result of the first query. So you'll still have to write your query and the joins but you won't have to manually type all the column names. \

Comment: so it would be: select * from ( select group_concat(concat(table_name,'.', column_name) separator ', ') 
from information_schema.columns
where table_name in ('Students', 'ClassRoster') ) where .... ?

Comment: No. Just run the first query. Copy the result to a notepad or something. Write your select statement with all 20 tables and joins. Copy the results from the first step and paste them into your `select` statement where you would specify the column names.

Comment: deal will try my best although i didn't see it yet but thank you so much for your help really

Answer (score 0):

You Should Use Alias in joining like this...

```
   Select E.Name , U.Name,E.Age,U.Age
   From 
   TblEmployee E 
   inner join 
   TblUser U on E.EmployeeId = U.EmployeeId
```

**Note : The above Query is only a Example So that you can go ahead**

**Edit:**  you can also do your column name what you want like this

```
   Select E.* , U.*, E.Age as Employee Age ,U.Age as UserAge 
   /* you can specify some column by E.Name and if you do not want then simplye do E.* by doing thing every column of your that table will be selected */
   From TblEmployee E 
   inner join 
   TblUser U on E.EmployeeId = U.EmployeeId
```

Comment: but what if i have 20 tables and each table have 10 attributes , i have to write 200 alias ? please advise

Comment: if you have Two 20 tables i would recommend you to use alias. no you have to write only 20 alias... Actually by using alias one can avoid the ambiguity between tables and there columns

Comment: how can i do it only with 20 alias ? should'nt i do it for all the attributes ?

Comment: @JadDaoud how many columns  you want to select in your Select Query ?

Comment: all the columns that are results of the join of the 20 tables

Comment: i am creating a view of the database

Comment: try 20 Alias and * for all columns if you do not want to name each column explicitly

Comment: can you show me please how ? i dont know to add * and specify also some columns

Comment: ok See my edit Specially Comment in the edit

Answer (score 0):

Just determined which columns you need in your view and use `AS` to assign a specific name to all of them.

This is an example. Both table have col1 and col2 :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e5732/2)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`Id` int, `Col1` varchar(1), `Col2` varchar(1), `Id2` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`Id`, `Col1`, `Col2`, `Id2`)
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 'B', 1),
    (2, 'B', 'C', 2),
    (3, 'D', 'E', 3)
;

CREATE TABLE Table2
    (`Id` int, `Col1` varchar(1), `Col2` varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    (`Id`, `Col1`, `Col2`)
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 'B'),
    (2, 'B', 'C'),
    (3, 'D', 'E')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Table1.Id as ID,
       Table1.Col1 as COL1,
       Table1.Col2 as COL2,
       Table2.Col1 as COL3,
       Table2.Col2 as COL4
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id2 = Table2.Id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e5732/2/0)**:

```
| ID | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
|----|------|------|------|------|
|  1 |    A |    B |    A |    B |
|  2 |    B |    C |    B |    C |
|  3 |    D |    E |    D |    E |
```

Comment: i like your answer thanks for this , but what if have 20 tables and each has 10 attributes ?:/